# Combining logistic and continuous regression with scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

In my dataset `X` I have two continuous variables `a, b` and two boolean variables `c, d`, making a total of 4 columns. 
I have a multidimensional target `y` consisting of two continuous variables `A, B` and one boolean variable `C`.

I would like to train a model on the columns of `X` to predict the columns of `y`. However, having tried `LinearRegression` on `X` it didn't perform so well (my variables vary several orders of magnitude and I have to apply suitable transforms to get the logarithms, I won't go into too much detail here). 
I think I need to use `LogisticRegression` on the boolean columns.

What I'd really like to do is combine both `LinearRegression` on the continuous variables and `LogisticRegression` on the boolean variables into a single pipeline. Note that all the columns of `y` depend on all the columns of `X`, so I can't simply train the continuous and boolean variables independently.

Is this even possible, and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've used something called a "Model Tree" (see link below) for the same sort of problem.

https://github.com/ankonzoid/LearningX/tree/master/advanced_ML/model_tree

But it will need to be customized for your application.  Please ask more questions if you get stuck using it.

Here's a screen shot of what it does

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your target data `Y` has multiple columns you need to use multi-task learning approach. Scikit-learn contains some multi-task learning algorithms for regression like `multi-task elastic-net` but you cannot combine logistic regression with linear regression because these algorithms use different loss functions to optimize. Also, you may try neural networks for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What i understand you want to do is to is to train a single model that both predicts a continuous variable and a class. You would need to combine both loses into one single loss to be able to do that which I don't think is possible in scikit-learn. However I suggest you use a deep learning framework (tensorflow, pytorch, etc) to implement your own model with the required properties you need which would be more flexible. In addition you can also tinker with solving the above problem using neural networks which would improve your results.